# newest kernel not loading

Tags: unity, kernel

I got problem (maybe after automatic update - not sure) with loading ubuntu (14.04 lts) - it is now showing weird graphic during booting - something like this [LINK](http://www.lxtxcx.info/storage/media/glitchy-pixel-art5/computer_crash.png) and then black screen insted of login screen (but it would still play sound of login screen). When I start previous kernel from GRUB menu it boot normaly. 
After few tries to solve it I gave up and just purge that newest kernel thinking it is corupted, leaving that working one as newest + update GRUB.
After reebot, that previously working kernel is doing the same thing as that deleted one - weird graphick and black login screen.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Is your hard disc partitioned such that you could install Ubuntu 14.04 again in a separate partition, in so doing making a clean install free of any clutter?
Does the same problem arise if you simply boot from a live CD?
I have four partitions (sometimes more), and one is the current 14.04, the other is 12.04, there is a separate partition where I keep all my data files called 'Global Docs', and then there is the 'Swap file'. I update the Ubuntu installations in 'leapfrog' fashion; meaning that I shall overwrite the 12.04 partition with say, 16.04, when it emerges.

Comment: disc is partitioned, but for now i would rather not make a fresh install. If i boot form the live cd it boot normaly, but as i stated if i boot from previus kernel it also boot normaly. It all worked fine on 14.04 for the last 2-3 weeks until yesterday